# Change meta theme-color in dark mode with javascript?

Tags: javascript

How can I merge this two script into one function,

```
<script>//<![CDATA[
function LMcheckCheckbox(){
    document.querySelectorAll(".checkbox").forEach(function(e) {      
       "darkmode"===localStorage.getItem("mode")?e.checked=!0:e.checked=!1
        })
    }
function darkMode(){
     localStorage.setItem("mode","darkmode"===localStorage.getItem("mode")?"light":"darkmode"),
     "darkmode"===localStorage.getItem("mode")?document.querySelector("body").classList.add("darkmode"):document.querySelector("body").classList.remove("darkmode"),
     LMcheckCheckbox()
 }
 function darkModeHide(){
      document.querySelectorAll(".darkmode-switch").forEach(function(e){
           e.parentNode.removeChild(e)
      })
 }
LMcheckCheckbox(),
"undefined"==typeof AzidBloggerSetting
 &&(AzidBloggerSetting={tombolDarkmode:!0}),           
 0==AzidBloggerSetting.tombolDarkmode&&darkModeHide();
    //]]>
</script>
```

and here the script to change meta theme color

```
$("meta[name='theme-color']").attr('content', '#333333');
```

how can I insert the second script in to the first script? I want to change the meta theme-color when the first script is active.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find where the darkmode is being activated and put your code in there.(unminify the code to see whats going on first)

i suggest you get a basic understanding of javascript before jumping into code!

as far as i understood, this is what you wanna do:

```
function LMcheckCheckbox() {
  document.querySelectorAll(".checkbox").forEach(function(e) {
    "darkmode" === localStorage.getItem("mode") ? e.checked = !0 : e.checked = !1
  })
}


function darkMode() {
// this is seemingly where the dark mode is being applyed so :
$("meta[name='theme-color']").attr('content', '#333333');
  localStorage.setItem("mode", "darkmode" === localStorage.getItem("mode") ? "light" : "darkmode"), "darkmode" === localStorage.getItem("mode") ? document.querySelector("body").classList.add("darkmode") : document.querySelector("body").classList.remove("darkmode"), LMcheckCheckbox()
}

function darkModeHide() {
  document.querySelectorAll(".darkmode-switch").forEach(function(e) {
    e.parentNode.removeChild(e)
  })
}
LMcheckCheckbox(), "undefined" == typeof AzidBloggerSetting && (AzidBloggerSetting = {
  tombolDarkmode: !0
}), 0 == AzidBloggerSetting.tombolDarkmode && darkModeHide();
```